# Problemas con setBounds

Tags: java, jframe

estoy intentado manipular un botón pero a pesar de que uso setBounds y pongo setLayout(null) el botón me aparece dentro de mi pantalla donde no lo especifico(centrado hasta arriba), de modo que obviamente esta ignorando el setBounds
   `public class Ventana extends JFrame {`

```
public Ventana(){

    super("El laberinto");//Establece el nombre de la ventana
    setSize(700, 700);//Establece el tamaño
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//Establece una operacion por deafaul al cerrar
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);//Hace que la pantalla no pueda manipularse de tamaño
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    Fondo f = new Fondo();
    setContentPane(f);
    Botones b = new Botones();
    add(b.b1v1);


}
}


  public class Botones extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

   ImageIcon ib1v1;
   JButton b1v1;

   public Botones(){

     ib1v1 = new 
    ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/siguiente.png"));
    b1v1 = new JButton(ib1v1);
    b1v1.setIcon(ib1v1);
    b1v1.setBounds(100,340,100,110);
   b1v1.setLayout(null);
   b1v1.addActionListener(this);





  }

     @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       if (e.getSource()==b1v1) {
  try{

  Ventana2 v2 = new Ventana2();
  v2.setVisible(true);
  v2.setSize(700,700); //Le damos tamaño al frame

  v2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  } catch(Exception excep) {
 System.exit(0);
   }
  }
  }
  }



 public class Juego extends JFrame{


  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Ventana v = new Ventana();



    }

   }


 public class Ventana2 extends JFrame{

    public Ventana2(){
      super("¿Listo?");//Establece el nombre de la ventana
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//Establece una 
      operacion por deafaul al cerrar
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);//Hace que la pantalla no pueda 
     manipularse de tamaño
    setResizable(false);
   }


  }


    public class Fondo extends JPanel{


    public Fondo(){

    }
   @Override
  public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
  Dimension tamanio = getSize();
  ImageIcon imagenFondo = new 
  ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/laberinto3.png"));
 g.drawImage(imagenFondo.getImage(),0,0,tamanio.width, tamanio.height, 
   null);
setOpaque(false);
super.paintComponent(g);
}




}
```

Comment: Podrias proporcionar el codigo completo tu codigo es algo confuso

Comment: Esperame un momento

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta original y agregar tu codigo faltante

Comment: Listo, ya se lo agregue

Answer (score 0):

`setBounds` está bien... lo que en verdad ocurre es que al no aplicar layout alguno al `contentPane` de tu clase `Ventana`, por defecto Java a través de su *Layout Manager* ajustará el `FlowLayout` y se verán los componentes en linea (uno al lado del otro) sin tomar en cuenta al `setBounds(100,340,100,110);`

Justo después de `Fondo f = new Fondo();` agrega `f.setLayout(null);`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]